# Python Histogram with one value

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm new to Matplotlib and I have just run through some code snippets and looked at the docs, but until now I have found nothing to help me create a histogram like so.

[image: Desired histogram]

My code is very simple, I only have one value I want to show as a histogram (percent_number)

My Problem is: how can I fix the y-scale to be 25 increments (e.g. 0, 25, 75, 100) and how do I use only one bin centered on the left side?

Sorry for this simple code, but I think I only need some simple advice.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import normal
percent_number = 100.0
my_bin = 25
plt.hist(percent_number, bins=my_bin)
plt.title("-")
plt.xlabel("-")
plt.ylabel("percent")
plt.show()
```

This outputs:

[image: Actual histogram]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **not a histogram but a bar plot** with a very narrow figure defined by `figsize`. You then set the x-axis limits equal to the bar width and hide the x-ticks. Complete code is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import normal

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1, 6)) # Define a thin figure

percent_number = 87
plt.bar(0.5, height=percent_number, width=1, align='center')
plt.ylabel("percent")
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 130)
plt.xticks([]) # Hide the x-ticks
plt.yticks([0, 25, 50, 75, 100]) # Set the desired y-ticks
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a narrow figure as shown in the answer by Bazingaa, another option would be to set the position and width of the axes yourself using [`ax.set_position()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_position.html). The list you pass is the new position of the axes: [left, bottom, width, height]. This means you can choose where the axes will appear and how wide/tall it will be. Note that the numbers are in figure coordinates:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.gca().set_position([0.2,0.1,0.1,0.8])

percent_number = 75

plt.bar(0, percent_number, align = "edge")
plt.title("-")
plt.xlabel("-")
plt.ylabel("percent")
plt.ylim(0,110)
plt.xticks([]) # remove x ticks
plt.yticks([0,25,50,75,100])
plt.margins(0) # remove extra whitespace

plt.show()
```

[image]